# Paypal amount calculations and discount :(

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to create a paypal form that will add 2 amount boxes together and minus 5$ off the the total amount if purchased by a specific date. I have been trying to do this for days and am not getting anywhere. Below is the code that I have; all help is appreciated :)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="ZNRGUCQ5GN4HU">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Gaslight Registration">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="40.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Is your Angel donation assigned? to who?">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://gaslight.endogaming.net">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://gaslight.endogaming.net">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Character Name">Character Name</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="on0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Angel Donation</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="60"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the code for making calculation what you want to achieve. All this you have to make your calculation in server side language like PHP or else which you are using and then storing the result variable to the amount input in HTML form. The calculation part can not be a part of Paypal HTML form so make your calculation apart from Paypal HTML form.